# Laravel: Contract file is not instantiable while building Controller

Tags: laravel, shopping-cart

I am trying to add a shopping cart function to my Laravel application. I installed darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart package from GitHub and have been following instructions in these two websites.

[TECHPOOL-Create a Shopping Cart with Laravel 6](https://salitha94.blogspot.com/2019/11/create-shopping-cart-with-laravel-6-part-1.html)

[LARASHOUT-Laravel E-Commerce Application Development – Checkout](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-e-commerce-application-development-checkout)

I was able to create most of the shopping cart function with the first website but it didn't cover checkouts and placing orders so I found the second website.

The problem is that the contract file is not working. Here is the error I got.

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
> Target [App\Contracts\OrderContract] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\CheckoutController].
> http://localhost:8000/checkout

Where I use the contract file is in the checkout process witch is explained in the second website. I made few changes in the codes so that it will be consistent with the first website but mostly I followed what the website says.

Here are the codes that are mentioned in the error.

**OrderContract.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Contracts;

interface OrderContract
{
    public function storeOrderDetails($params);
}
```

**CheckoutController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Contracts\OrderContract;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class CheckoutController extends Controller
{
    protected $orderRepository;

    public function __construct(OrderContract $orderRepository)
    {
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
    }

    public function getCheckout()
    {
        return view('checkout');
    }

    public function placeOrder(Request $request)
    {
        // Before storing the order we should implement the
        // request validation which I leave it to you
        $order = $this->orderRepository->storeOrderDetails($request->all());

        dd($order);
    }
}
```

**OrderRepository.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use Cart;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Product;
use App\Models\OrderItem;
use App\Contracts\OrderContract;

class OrderRepository extends BaseRepository implements OrderContract
{
    public function __construct(Order $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function storeOrderDetails($params)
    {
        $order = Order::create([
            'order_number'      =>  'ORD-' . strtoupper(uniqid()),
            'status'            =>  'pending',
            'grand_total'       =>  Cart::getSubTotal(),
            'item_count'        =>  Cart::getTotalQuantity(),
            'table_number'      =>  $params['table_number'],
            'name'              =>  $params['name'],
            'notes'             =>  $params['notes']
        ]);

        if ($order) {

            $items = Cart::getContent();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                // A better way will be to bring the product id with the cart items
                // you can explore the package documentation to send product id with the cart
                $product = Product::where('name', $item->name)->first();

                $orderItem = new OrderItem([
                    'product_id'    =>  $product->id,
                    'quantity'      =>  $item->quantity,
                    'price'         =>  $item->getPriceSum()
                ]);

                $order->items()->save($orderItem);
            }
        }

        return $order;
    }
}
```

**RepositoryServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Contracts\OrderContract;
use App\Repositories\OrderRepository;

class RepositoryServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $repositories = [
        OrderContract::class            =>          OrderRepository::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        foreach ($this->repositories as $interface => $implementation) {
            $this->app->bind($interface, $implementation);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I'm not really familiar with the contract concept since I only started learning Laravel recently and I'm completely lost here. Maybe the problem is that I haven't created another file that is necessary or maybe something else.

Any help would be appreciated as I have tried multiple methods with no success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: the container would need to know what instance you want when asking for this interface ... so probably the part you are missing ... you need to set a binding in the container for this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is expected...your contract should point to a Solid class else it's going to fail while trying to resolve it out of the container. So this is what you should do:

1. Create a class that implements that trait.
2. Go to your AppServiceProvider and bind it to that contract like this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
        $this->app->bind(\App\Contracts\OrderContract::class, App\Repositories\ClassImplementingOrderContract::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

this should fix your problem.

Comment: This is the binding `$this->app->bind(\App\Contracts\OrderContract::class, App\Repositories\ClassImplementingOrderContract::class);`, so the class your going to create will look like this `class ClassImplementingOrderContract implements OrderContract {}`.

Comment: Hey there,
When I created the OrderContract.php file I also created OrderRepository.php file  RepsitorySeviceProvider.php file(I will add the codes to my question). I think what I did with RepsitorySeviceProvider.php file is what you mean in advice no.2. But I'm not sure about advice no.1. Is this about OrderRepository.php file?
Thank you so much for helping me out.

Comment: Add the code to your question and make sure you registered the `RepsitorySeviceProvider.` with Laravel else.

Comment: I don't think I have registered the RepsitorySeviceProvider.php yet. Maybe this is the problem... Could you tell me which file I should find to do this?

Comment: There are to ways to do it. First is through your `config/app.php` file, scroll down to line `177` and drop it right underneath the other service providers. Or you can register it in the register method of your AppServiceProvider like this: `$this->register(RepsitorySeviceProvider::class);`. Pick which feels natural to you.

Comment: Tank you so much tsommie!
I added the line in config/app.php and now it's working!
I woundn't have figured this out on my own, thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This error could caused even if you have forget to add "RepositoryServiceProvider" into "config/app.php" 's serviceProviders array.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).